# django username in url, instead of id

Tags: django, url, friendly-url

in a mini virtual community, i have a profile_view function, so that i can view the profile of any registered user. The profile view function has as a parameter the id of the user wich the profile belongs to, so that when i want to access the profile of user 2 for example, i call it like that:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile_view/2/

My problem is that i would like to have the username in the url, and NOT the id. 
I try to modify my code as follows, but it doesn't work still. Here is my code:

view:

```
def profile_view(request, user):
        u = User.objects.get(pk=user)
        up = UserProfile.objects.get(created_by = u)
        cv = UserProfile.objects.filter(created_by = User.objects.get(pk=user))
        blog = New.objects.filter(created_by = u) 
        replies = Reply.objects.filter(reply_to = blog)
        vote = Vote.objects.filter(voted=blog)
        following = Relations.objects.filter(initiated_by = u)
        follower = Relations.objects.filter(follow = u)
    return render_to_response('profile/publicProfile.html', {
        'vote': vote,
        'u':u,  
        'up':up, 
        'cv': cv, 
        'ing': following.order_by('-date_initiated'),  
        'er': follower.order_by('-date_follow'),
        'list':blog.order_by('-date'),
        'replies':replies
        }, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                        url(r'^profile_view/(?P<user>\d+)/$', 
                           profile_view,
                           name='profile_view'),
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't show what you have tried, or where you are having trouble. This is fairly simple, after all - just pass a username string to the function instead of an integer, and look up based on that.

```
def profile_view(request, username):
    u = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

and modify your url to allow strings rather than integers:

```
url(r'^profile_view/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 
                       profile_view,
                       name='profile_view'),
```

Comment: based on what I see in django/contrib/auth/forms.py I think a better regex to use to grab the username is

    (?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)

Comment: What if username is an email and you don't want this info to be public? You could use user first and last name, but this could be duplicated, so I think we should add an ID or a hash on the ID.

Answer (score 12):

Here's how I do it using class based generic views and the use of slugs. It's surprisingly easy and requires only a few lines of code with the help of slugs.

```
# accounts/views.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = "username"
    template_name = "userprofile.html"

# accounts/urls.py
from views import UserProfileView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # By user ID
    url(r'^profile/id/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UserProfileView.as_view()),
    # By username
    url(r'^profile/username/(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/$', UserProfileView.as_view()),
)
```

Now you can access both the user like `accounts/profile/id/123/` as well as `accounts/profile/username/gertvdijk/`.

What's happening here?

- The usually required `pk` URL parameter is omitted and replaced by `slug` in the URL pattern. This is accepted by the view, because...
- The slug parameter is being used by the DetailView (or any other SingleObjectMixin-based view) to find the object on `User.username` by the use of `model = User` and `slug_field = "username"`. ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object))
- Because a slug field is optional, the view is also happily serving using just the `pk` parameter.

Comment: What would happen if the username had any of .@+ as these are not valid characters in a slug?

Comment: How do you do this in the case of extends User to UserProfile (you know to get more fields for a user). The User model has the 'username' field but the UserProfile model has the customize fields that I wan to show too.

Comment: @RicardoGonzales That's pretty straightforward... change the `model` and the `slug_field`. Works with every Django model, this recipe, not just with `User`s.

Answer (score 7):

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:username>/', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user_detail'),
]
```

With class based view.

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):

    model = User
    slug_field = "username"
    slug_url_kwarg = "username"
    template_name = "account/user_detail.html"

    def get_object(self):

        object = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get("username"))

        # only owner can view his page
        if self.request.user.username == object.username:
            return object
        else:
            # redirect to 404 page
            print("you are not the owner!!")
```

I have tested in Django 2.1.

Answer (score 3):

Add in the top of the file:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
```

and replace

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=user)
```

with

```
u = get_object_or_404(User, <login>=user)
```

where **login** is the username field in User model.

Comment: i've replaced just as you said, and it  says i have a Syntax error at the line "u = User.objects.get(<login>=user)
"

Comment: Replace login with the name of the field that's user name. I don't know how it's called there. Also look at the other answer and fix the url.

Answer (score 1):

For Django 2.0 and above:

```
path(‘profile/<username>/, views.profile, name=‘profile’),
```