# Error passing the username to a Generic DetailView - django 1.4.3

Tags: django, django-urls, django-generic-views

First of all, I have read this [django username in url, instead of id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013098/django-username-in-url-instead-of-id/3013160#3013160) it helped, but did not solve my problem.  I do not want to write any code in `views.py` if I can help it.

Things I've tried under `urls.py`.  Note: In both cases I get `name 'username' is not defined`.

## 1

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
        login_required(
            DetailView.as_view(
                model=User,
                username=username,
                template_name='account/user_detail.html'),
            login_url='/accounts/login/'
        )
    ),
)
```

## 2

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
        login_required(
            DetailView.as_view(
                model=User,
                queryset=User.objects.get(username=username),
                template_name='account/user_detail.html'),
            login_url='/accounts/login/'
        )
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that sort of dynamic filtering in the urlconf. Subclass DetailView and override `get_queryset` to filter on `self.kwargs['username']`.