# Why is my django template setting user to the same as object?

Tags: python, django

I'm a definite newbie to django, and have used tutorials and stack overflow a lot to design my app.

My app tracks casework for users. One thing I need it to be able to do is to be logged in as one user, and look at the caseload for another user.

When this page comes up, the bit that would normally say "Logout Joe Bloggs", where Joe Bloggs is the logged in user, says "Logout Fitzwilliam Darcy" where Fitzwilliam Darcy is the user I should be viewing the casework of.

I don't really want to continue developing the app until I've fixed it, in case this is a symptom of an underlying problem that will cause more issues in future.

I'll add what I think all the relevant bits are here, but if there's anything else needed, let me know and I'll be happy to edit.

```
#urls.py

url(r'cases/(?P<slug>\w+)',views.UserCasesView.as_view(),name='cases'),

#views.py

@method_decorator(login_required,name='dispatch')
class UserCasesView(generic.DetailView):

    model = models.User
    template_name = 'caseworkclub/caseworker_detail.html'
    slug_field = 'username'

#models.py

class User(AbstractUser):                                           

    association = models.ForeignKey('Association',null=True)

    def full_name(self):
        return("{} {}".format(self.first_name,self.last_name)

    def open_cases(self):
        return(Case.objects.filter(closed__isnull=True,caseworker=self))
```

The slug bit is so that the username can be in the URL according to [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16258084/4699448)

It might also be worth explaining, if the `models.py` bit doesn't give it away, that I've extended the base user class and am using that, rather than the user profile technique. The problem seems to have come about since changing the slug bit above, though.

Any help hugely appreciated, and as I said - any more info, happy to provide!

James

Comment: What happens if you change `user` to `request.user` in the logout section?

Comment: Can you show your templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you did not override the `get_context_data()` method of your `UserCasesView` class with a sensible default. It currently uses the model name (which also happens to be `user`) which conflicts with the built-in `user` variable which is set by `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` context processor.

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data):

> **Context variables override values from template context processors**
>
> Any variables from `get_context_data()` take precedence over context variables from context processors. For example, if your view sets the model attribute to User, the default context object name of user would override the user variable from the django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth() context processor. Use get_context_object_name() to avoid a clash.

Try changing the object name from `user` to something else (such as `case_user`):

```
class UserCasesView(generic.DetailView):
    ...
    context_object_name = 'case_user'
```

Comment: This solves it, thanks! Am amazed that I only had to change that one line, and not add a reference to what I added anywhere?